# unable to telnet port 40901

Tags: linux, linux-networking

Server port is open in Network firewall as well as iptables disabled on server.

We able to telnet port in same network but unable to telnet using localhost/127.0.0.1 and using different network.

Find below output which will be help you to analyse issue.

**[root@localhost ~]# netstat -paln | grep 40901

tcp        0      0 10.141.36.41:40901          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      48292/./as-agent

[root@localhost ~]# telnet 10.141.36.41 40901

Trying 10.141.36.41...

Connected to 10.141.36.41.

Escape character is '^]'.

^]

telnet> quit

Connection closed.

[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost 40901

Trying ::1...

telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused

Trying 127.0.0.1...

telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application only bound to 10.141.36.41. You cannot reach it on any other address.

To resolve the problem, change the application's settings.